# How can I standardize the phone numbers in a text file?

Tags: text-processing

I periodically receive a text file with phone numbers formatted in wildly different ways: `##########`, `###-###-####`, `(###) ###-###`, etc. Usually there's ten digits, but I've seen `+1 (###) ###-####`.

Eventually the file gets imported into a database, but for reasons I won't go into, it'd be handy to have the phone numbers have a standard format, `(###) ###-####`.

The only constant is that the phone numbers always fall between the second and third tab character on each line.

Is there a way to do this from the command line?

Comment: The phone number system you mention in your question hast been introduced by Germany in the 1950s and withdrawn soon as it was not flexible enough. The US later imported that scheme and unless you only need to deal with US phone numbers, you need to be aware of much longer phone numbers. IIRC, current international rules require that the contry code (1 in case of the US, but up to three digits in general) + the rest of the phone number may be up to 16 digits. BTW: the area code could be from one to 5 digits.

Comment: To standardize, one would do well to use a standard.  An appropriate standard for telephone numbers is E.164 from the International Telecommunications Union.

Comment: This particular system uses only US phone numbers, and the "standard" is for human readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should cover you as long as the file is as you have described. The command preserves information before and after the phone number and formats it in the way that you asked for. If the output looks good, add the `-i` option to `sed` to edit it in place or provide it with output redirection using `> output_file` at the end.

```
sed -E "s/(.*\t.*\t)\+?1?[[:space:]]?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?.*([0-9]{3}).*([0-9]{4})(.*)/\1\(\2\)\ \3-\4\5/g" filename
```

I tested it on a file containing this text:

```
    jfk 902-765-9292 hat jump cat
    jk  902 819 2244 hat jump cat
    98  902 823-4456 hat jump cat
    78h +1 075 242 1566 hat jump cat
jklj    kjlj    +1 075-242-1566 hat jump cat
jk  jkj +1 (075) 242-1566 hat jump cat
    kj  (204) 799-9810 hat jump cat
kj  89  (204)-799-9810 hat jump cat
```

The output was:

```
    jfk (902) 765-9292 hat jump cat
    jk  (902) 819-2244 hat jump cat
    98  (902) 823-4456 hat jump cat
    78h (075) 242-1566 hat jump cat
jklj    kjlj    (075) 242-1566 hat jump cat
jk  jkj (075) 242-1566 hat jump cat
    kj  (204) 799-9810 hat jump cat
kj  89  (204) 799-9810 hat jump cat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a regular expression that matches any of the formats, and captures the digits then re-substitutes them in your desired format.

For example, to match and capture a sequence of three decimal digits optionally surrounded by parentheses with an Extended Regular Expression (ERE), you can write `\(?([0-9]{3})\)?` while `[- ]?` matches an optional hyphen or space. Building up in this way

```
\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[- ]?([0-9]{3})[- ]?([0-9]{4})
```

will match 3 digits optionally parenthesized, optionally followed by a hyphen or space, then  more digits optionally followed by a hyphen or space, followed by 4 digits.

Applying the expression in a `sed` substitution:

```
$ cat <<EOF | sed -E 's/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[- ]?([0-9]{3})[- ]?([0-9]{4})/(\1) \2-\3/g'
I periodically receive a text file with phone numbers formatted 
in wildly different ways: 123 456-7890, 123 456-7890, 123 456-7890, 
etc. Usually there's ten digits, but I've seen +1 555 456-7890.
EOF
I periodically receive a text file with phone numbers formatted 
in wildly different ways: (123) 456-7890, (123) 456-7890, (123) 456-7890, 
etc. Usually there's ten digits, but I've seen +1 (555) 456-7890.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the field and the re-format it; here's an awk script that looks for three variations and re-formats them (before default-printing the reconstituted line):

```
$3 ~ /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ {
        $3="(" substr($3, 1, 3) ") " substr($3, 4, 3) "-" substr($3, 7, 4)
}

$3 ~ /^[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ {
        $3="(" substr($3, 1, 3) ") " substr($3, 5, 3) "-" substr($3, 9, 4)
}

$3 ~ /^\+1 \([0-9][0-9][0-9]\) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ {
        $3="(" substr($3, 5, 3) ") " substr($3, 10, 3) "-" substr($3, 14, 4)
}

1
```

Save that to a file, perhaps `phone.awk`, then call it with: `awk -F $'\t' -f phone.awk < input`.